# VBA calls error 6 Overflow when using DateSerial after 1989

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to use DateSerial in this situations:

`myDate = SerialDate(1969, 2, 12)` as the example provided here: [DateAndTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.dateandtime.dateserial?view=netframework-4.8)

However, when I try using it after 1990 it gives me the overflow error.

`myDate = SerialDate(1990, 1, 1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `Dim` *myDate* correctly.

This:

```
Sub ThisFail()
    Dim myDate As Integer
    myDate = DateSerial(1990, 1, 1)
End Sub
```

will overflow.  This:

```
Sub ThisWorks()
    Dim myDate As Date
    myDate = DateSerial(1990, 1, 1)
End Sub
```

will not.

Answer (score 4):

The link you provide is for DotNET and not for VBA.

And the function in VBA is called `DateSerial(year, month, day)` not `SerialDate`.
See [DateSerial function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateserial-function).

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestDate()
    Dim myDate As Date
    myDate = DateSerial(1969, 2, 12) 'February 12ᵗʰ 1969

    Debug.Print myDate 
End Sub
```